# How do you delete an 'service action' you've created in the Box Application Editor?

Tags: box-api

Having created a Service Action in the editor, it's unclear how to delete it.  There doesn't appear to be an action in the 'edit service action' screen, nor in the application edit screen.  Am I stuck with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write into Box support to have them remove it.

Comment: This would've been the last thing I'd have guessed.  Thanks!